# Host Not reachble on a Network Interface

Tags: linux, dhcp, network-adapter, gateway

I have two network interfaces on my linux system. When I select eth0 as default gateway , everything works fine. I can connect to the system from other computers, but when I select eth1 as default gateway. Host is not reachable at all.

How can I diagnose this issue ? Below is ifconfig output when I select eth1 as default gateway

[image]

[image]

Comment: We're going to need a LOT more information.  Routes, network setup, etc.

Comment: @jnovack I have attached the output of route and network file. What do you meant network setup?

Comment: Is eth0 your public internet connection and eth1 your private intranet?  Is this a linux router?

Comment: @jnovack eth0 is our intranet and eth1 is connected to a router in a different network. I am connecting from our intranet when eth0 is default gateway , it works may be because of this reason. I am not sure whether our intranet and network configured on eht1 can talk to each other(This is remote machine configured by my admin). I need to check this with admin. But wont I be able to connect to eth0 IP, since we are in same network?

Comment: There you go, answered your own question. It is impossible to tell if this will work unless your admin has made the 192.168. network talk to the 9.5. network.

Comment: Why do you feel you need to change the set-up of the default GW if eth0 works? Which IP range are you connecting from when eth1 fails?

Comment: @tink : We eth1 in case of network or eth0 hardware fails . How can I know the second part?

Comment: @jnovack : I got the part where i am unable to connect to the machine with IP allocated to eth1, but should it be possible to connect using IP address on eth0 since we are in the same network?

Comment: Those two IPs are NOT on the same network.  They may be connected to the same hardware, but in terms of routing they probably aren't connected at all.

Comment: @tink I was referring to network on eth0 remote machine and my desktop, they are in same network. I am able to connect to IP allocated to eth0 from my desktop when eth0 is default gateway but not able to connect using the same IP when eth1 is the default gateway. Is it because gateway also plays role on host identity?